# Is it possible to have Word 2007 access a MySQL database?

Tags: microsoft-word, database, mail-merge

What I essentially want is some way to expand my mail merge system. If an account number gets sent to a word document via mail merge, I would like some way for Word to connect to a MySQL database and use that account number to execute additional queries and retrieve information.

For one, I don't see the option in Word to create database connections. Excel has a ribbon tab for data connections, so I tried playing around with it and in typical Microsoft fashion, they seem to have "forgotten" that any non-Microsoft products exist and only let me choose MSQL or Access databases.

I googled for a solution and the only real promising thing I found required full Visual Studio tools, which I don't have (and this is for work so I can't really get by with using the personal free editions).

Is there **any** way I can manage this? If Word cannot connect directly to a MySQL database, can it do something like execute a perl script that connects to the database and returns query results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1. Install the [**MySQL ODBC driver**](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html).
2. [**Create an ODBC data source**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html#connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-1)
3. When doing your merge choose the ODBC source when setting your data source for the merge (instead of Access or Excel, etc).

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have worked. I still have a few remaining issues (specifically, how to query that information), but that's beyond the scope of this question so I'll consider this one solved.